# Inject dependency with "constructor scope" - autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I am using autofac 3.5.x and I have a setup similar to this:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA { }
public class ServiceB : IServiceB { public ServiceB(IServiceA sa) { } }
public class ServiceC : IServiceC { public ServiceC(IServiceA sa) { } }
public class ServiceD : IServiceD { public ServiceD(IServiceA sa, IServiceB sb, IServiceC sc) {} }
```

In my container I have the following registrations:

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>.As<IServiceA>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>.As<IServiceB>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceC>.As<IServiceC>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceD>.As<IServiceD>();
```

Here is what I want: When I request a new `IServiceD` from the container, I want the same `IServiceA` instance to be injected into `IServiceD` and its dependencies `IServiceB` and `IServiceC`. I am not looking for a global singleton scope though. Next time I ask for an `IServiceD` instance it *must* be created with a new instance of `IServiceA` (I know you cannot create an instance of an interface, but I think you get the point).

To illustrate; when I ask the autofac container for an `IServiceD` I want the following to happen:

```
public class ServiceD : IServiceD
{
    public ServiceD(IServiceA sa, IServiceB sb, IServiceC sc)
    {
        // SA should be the same (but it is not)
        sa.GetHashCode() == sb.GetServiceA().GetHashCode() == sc.GetServiceA().GetHashCode()
    }
}
```

Please note that the `GetServiceA()` method is only included to illustrate my point.

So yeah, I guess I am looking for some way to tell autofac that when it resolves `IServiceD` it should create a singleton of `ServiceA` but only for the scope of `ServiceD`'s constructor.

Right now, I use autofacs support for delegate factories, and ask for:

```
public ServiceD(IServiceA sa, Func<IServiceA, IServiceB> fb, Func<IServiceA, IServiceC> fc) : IServiceD
{
     var sb = fb(sa); // Manually inject the same instance of ServiceA
     var sc = fc(sa); // Manually inject the same instance of ServiceA

     // ServiceA is now the same instance
     sa.GetHashCode() == sb.GetServiceA().GetHashCode() == sc.GetServiceA().GetHashCode()
}
```

This gets me going, but I have a feeling it can be done better - which is why I am turning to the experts now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InstancePerLifetimeScope` may suit your need. It allows you to have a single instance per lifetime scope.

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<IServiceA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>().As<IServiceB>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceC>().As<IServiceC>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceD>().As<IServiceD>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Then, each time you resolve `IServiceD` in a new scope you will have a single instance of `IServiceA`

```
using (ILifetimeScope scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    // only an instance of IServiceA will be created for this scope
    scope.Resolve<IServiceD>(); 
}
```

If you can't create a new `ILifetimeScope` you can use the `Owned<T>` type which is a lightweight lifetimescope.

```
using (Owned<IServiceD> ownedD = container.Resolve<Owned<IServiceD>>())
{
    IServiceD serviceD = ownedD.Value;                 
}
```

Each time you resolve a `Owned<IserviceD>` a new `ILifetimeScope` will be created and only a single `IServiceA` will be created.

If it is not enough you can play with [`InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-matching-lifetime-scope) but it will make your code and registration quite difficult to read and debug. `InstancePerLifetimeScope` should be enough.

Another solution is to use this kind of registration.

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
    IServiceA serviceA = ctx.Resolve<IServiceA>();
    IServiceB serviceB = ctx.Resolve<IServiceB>(TypedParameter.From(serviceA));
    IServiceC serviceC = ctx.Resolve<IServiceC>(TypedParameter.From(serviceA));
    IServiceD serviceD = ctx.Resolve<IServiceD>(TypedParameter.From(serviceA), TypedParameter.From(serviceB), TypedParameter.From(serviceC));
    return serviceD;
}).As<IServiceD>();
```

But is not really elegant.

Comment: Hi Cyril, sorry for accepting your answer this late. I appreciate your input. Your tip regarding `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` was the one I needed to move on. Thanks.